# includegraphics keeps invisible part of image

Tags: pdfpages, includegraphics

When using `includepdf` and `includegraphics` to include a pdf or an image, the trimmed part is only hidden but not removed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[trim={10mm 10mm 50mm 10mm}]{example-image.pdf}

\includepdf[trim={10mm 10mm 50mm 10mm},clip]{example-image.pdf}

\includepdf[clip,trim={10mm 10mm 50mm 10mm}]{example-image.pdf}

\end{document}
```

My questions are:

1. Why is it done this way?
2. Can I somehow remove the invisible parts?
3. Should I remove the invisible parts?

I tried using the `clip` key but it does not seem to work.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for your reply. I already tried that. Updated the question.

Comment: related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462372/included-pdf-image-has-invisible-but-selectable-text?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: oh sorry I misread your question, hidden but not removed, yes by design (and not feasible to change)

Comment: I suppose the question would be HOW do you want to clip it exactly? For jpg you could do losslessly, but true lossless clipping involves changing the clip size, and if lossy, how exactly. There is no such singular thing as a clipped image. Images can also be re-used in the same pdf (at different clippings).  You could ask the same question about why images inserted are not saved in the pdf at a different size (without clipping)